# Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu: ssh-agent running but ssh-add complains "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"

Tags: linux, ssh, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL with Ubuntu on my laptop to develop on Linux while I'm away from my desktop (with native Linux, where I don't experience any problems like this). I have private git repo setup, and I use ssh to connect to it. I have ssh configured (in `.ssh/config`), and I have multiple keys for my VPS, GitHub, other VPS user account etc. so I use `ssh-add` on my desktop to manage them. But on my laptop, in WSL, when I try to connect to my VPS, ssh asks for the passphrase to the key. When I try to do `ssh-add .ssh/mykey` I get an error:

```
$ ssh-add .ssh/mykey
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

But `ssh-agent` is running:

```
$ ps -e | grep ssh
4455 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
5517 ?        00:00:00 sshd
6164 pts/0    00:00:00 ssh
```

I don't see why is there a problem. If I kill currently running `ssh-agent` and launch it again (using `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`) it works fine.

Comment: For normal SSH in Windows to WSL in `localhost`, the configuration `PasswordAuthentication yes` must be added in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are starting ssh-agent but you are not setting up the variable pointing to it.

When you just run `ssh-agent` it will output something like:

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-UfASAcTfsiJm/agent.77; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=78; export SSH_AGENT_PID;`

Copy that as commands and paste to bash, or make your life simpler by just executing:

`` eval `ssh-agent` ``

After that variables will be set and ssh-add will know how to connect to ssh-agent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with WSL (as of 2019) you can start multiple shells from the Window subsystem, they are aware of each others but don't inherit any variables. Therefore they don't know that ssh-agent is already running.

I managed to get it working by adding this bit of code to my .bashrc:

```
source /tmp/ssh-agent >/dev/null 2>&1
ssh-add 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  ssh-agent >/tmp/ssh-agent
  source /tmp/ssh-agent >/dev/null 2>&1
  ssh-add
fi
```

Maybe not the most eloquent code, but it solves the problem.

May 2023 update - I now use this instead, maybe a bit cleaner

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add -t 0 .ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: this was the case for me, was using two terminals and ssh agent wasnt really available in the other terminal where i did not do eval ssh-agent